# Foreach too slow

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays:

```
$questions: pid => name
$answers: pid => rid
```

It inserts in the database all the questions (pid) and if there is an answer (rid) it inserts the answer; if no answer it inserts 0.

```
foreach($questions as $value) {
    $idanswer = ($answers[$value[pid]]) ? $answers[$value[pid]] : 0;
    $idquestion = $value[pid];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO solucion ( rid, pid) VALUES ( '$idanswer ', '$idquestion ')";
    $db - > query($sql);
}
```

In my inexperience, I use foreach for almost everything, but in this case too slow. Any advice?

Comment: I highly doubt this has anything to do with `foreach`, but rather your database queries.

Comment: `In my inexperience, I use foreach for almost everything` I'm sorry to hear that. You should instead be forming _one_ `INSERT` query for all your new rows.

Comment: @Svish: The `INSERT` will be fast; 1,500 of them will not be. Wrapping a single `INSERT` in a `foreach` is wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can assure you the loop will be close to instantaneous if you remove `$db->query($sql);`. It's running the query which takes time, which means the solution, like others have already answered here, is to minimize the number of queries you run. Nothing to do with "the speed of foreach".

Comment: @Svish: Agreed. But trying to claim that it has nothing to do with `foreach` seems like a strange thing to say, when it is the OP's choice to use `foreach` to solve his problem that is causing the delays. Anyway, turns out we're both saying the same thing, in opposite ways. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question title is "foreach too slow". The fact however is that `foreach` is very fast. Doing hundreds/thousands of database queries on the other hand, will take quite a bit of time. The solution here is not to avoid `foreach`, but rather to use it to build a single query you can run once after the loop, instead of running one query for every question.

Comment: @Svish The question title is horrendous. Also I'm well aware of what the solution is, as you can see from the answer that I posted more than 4 hours ago. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of run a query per each row to insert, why don't you just insert all rows in a single query? The query is the expensive cost you are paying there, it's surely not the foreach the problem.

Why don't you go with something along the lines of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO solucion (rid, pid) VALUES ";
$vls = array();
foreach($questions as $value) {
    $idanswer = ($answers[$value[pid]]) ? $answers[$value[pid]] : 0;
    $idquestion = $value[pid];
    $vls[] = " ( '$idanswer ', '$idquestion ')";

}
$sql .= implode(', ', $vls);
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Hurray! Spoon-feeding! Because _that_ makes our industry better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, we all need examples.

Comment: _Sometimes._ And in those times, examples should _complement_ a prose-based explanation. You just handed him a piece of code with nothing further... which is a great shame. It's also the reason that SO is being flooded by "make my codez for me" non-questions.

Comment: What the OP needs is a pointer in the right direction - the OP will just copy and paste your code and have no idea why or what it does

Comment: @ManseUK, that kind of people cannot be saved anyway. If he is smart he will try to understand it, if he is not he won't. It's not out responsibility to force people into making the smart decision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, with all due respect. I do not baby-sit anyone. Is he willing to learn? He will learn even better from this answer. Isn't he? It's not my responsibility. People who dig into answers will always be a better programmer than those who don't.

Comment: @Jueecy It _is_ your responsibility. It is the responsibility of all of us. Otherwise why on earth are you here? This answer is much better now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, last time I checked this was a Q&A website, not a "Let's learn together" one. People come here for to find answers, not teachers. But I guess it's just a point of view.

Comment: I fail to see the distinction.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of wrapping a single `INSERT` query in a PHP loop, use a PHP loop to build up a *single* `INSERT` query in a string, then execute that single query at the end.

**Hint:** [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) can insert *multiple* rows at the same time.

Although a single `INSERT` is fast, the combined round-trip of a MySQL query is *always* going to scale poorly because you are repeating the connection/communication/interpretation/file-access overhead for *each* of your `N` array elements... all of which is needless.

Comment: You can also use transaction. Just begin it before the loop and commit after. It will increase perfomance. Only works with InnoDb table engine.

Comment: Very much. Tested on 800k inserts. And again, it will increate performance a lot only with InnoDb

Comment: @Vadim But you're still doing 800k round-trips unnecessarily. That said, you wouldn't use a _single_ string/query for **800k** rows.

Comment: You are right. I suggested this option as an alternative way to solve the issue. It mostly depends on the subject, if you need to get last inserted ID and use it in another insert and perform some manipulation you couldnt use batch inserts.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend building one INSERT-statement that insert multiple values since the structure is equal for each record.

```php
$values = [];
foreach($questions as $value) {
  $idanswer = ($answers[$value[pid]]) ? $answers[$value[pid]] : 0;
  $idquestion = $value[pid];
  array_push($values, "('$idanswer', '$idquestion')");
 }
 $db->query("INSERT INTO solucion (rid, pid) VALUES " . implode(',', $values));
```

The snippet above will build an INSERT-statement in the following form

```sql
INSERT INTO table (column, column) VALUES ('value', 'value'), ('value', 'value')
```

and preferably reduce the number of database hits needed to insert all records.

For complete reference of the INSERT-statement, please read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Comment: **WHY** add another duplicate of an answer already here ... **UPVOTE** the current answer ...

Comment: I upvoted the textual answer which described the problem and its solution very well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's slow because you are performing 1 transaction per foreach iteration.

Build your whole SQL statement in the foreach loop then execute it once after the foreach completes.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) VALUES(1,2),(4,5),(7,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of run multiple insert statements, build up one INSERT statement and then run just the one statement. For example see below.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO solucion ( rid, pid) VALUES";

foreach($questions as $value) {
    $idanswer = ($answers[$value[pid]]) ? $answers[$value[pid]] : 0;
    $idquestion = $value[pid];
    $query .= " ( '$idanswer ', '$idquestion '),";
}

$query = rtrim($query, ",").";";

$db - > query($sql);
```

Comment: **WHY** add another duplicate of an answer already here ... **UPVOTE** the current answer ...

Comment: I clicked answer before any answer was here and by the time I had clicked submit the other answer was put up, I'm just not as fast as some people when answering, sorry.